# How can I creating an autocomplete textbox with the "Search" magnifying Glass

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

If I create a [textbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textbox) in a Firefox with a [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/textbox.type) of "autocomplete" I am able to get autocomplete working properly.  However, the textbox is a intended to be used as search textbox (with autocomplete).  Thus, in addition to autocomplete I also want the standard UI used when the textbox has a type of "search." In particular, Firefox shows a magnifying glass that turns into an "X" when the user types into it.

Is there a clean (or, failing that, not so clean) way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox Searchbar ,the one on right top usually,  has `type="autocomplete"` and has the `searchbutton`

First: browser.xul of firefox has a `toolbaritem` which `searchbar` nested in it.

```xml
    <toolbaritem id="search-container" title="&searchItem.title;"
               align="center" class="chromeclass-toolbar-additional"
               flex="100" persist="width" removable="true">
    <searchbar id="searchbar" flex="1"/>
    </toolbaritem>
```

`searchbar` has the following css property in browser.css.

```css
    searchbar {
      -moz-binding: url("chrome://browser/content/search/search.xml#searchbar");
    }
```

That url in css property brings us to search.xml which has the `textbox` and the `searchbutton` is added to `textbox` in a `hbox` as far as i can understand.

```xml
    <xul:textbox class="searchbar-textbox"
               anonid="searchbar-textbox"
               type="autocomplete"
               flex="1"
               autocompletepopup="PopupAutoComplete"
               autocompletesearch="search-autocomplete"
               autocompletesearchparam="searchbar-history"
               timeout="250"
               maxrows="10"
               completeselectedindex="true"
               showcommentcolumn="true"
               tabscrolling="true"
               xbl:inherits="disabled,disableautocomplete,searchengine,src,newlines">
    <xul:box>
      <xul:button class="searchbar-engine-button"
                  type="menu"
                  anonid="searchbar-engine-button">
        <xul:image class="searchbar-engine-image" xbl:inherits="src"/>
        <xul:image class="searchbar-dropmarker-image"/>
        <xul:menupopup class="searchbar-popup"
                       anonid="searchbar-popup">
          <xul:menuseparator/>
          <xul:menuitem class="open-engine-manager"
                        anonid="open-engine-manager"
                        label="&cmd_engineManager.label;"
                        oncommand="openManager(event);"/>
        </xul:menupopup>
      </xul:button>
     </xul:box>
     <xul:hbox class="search-go-container">
      <xul:image class="search-go-button"
                 anonid="search-go-button"
                 onclick="handleSearchCommand(event);"
                 tooltiptext="&searchEndCap.label;" />
     </xul:hbox>
    </xul:textbox>
```

Well this is not an total answer, but gives a head start for you or others who may contribute I guess. For further detail you can dig omni.jar in mozilla firefox directory.

Comment: This gives me enough information to solve my problem.  The basic trick I was missing was that textbox elements can contain other elements.